# Replacing new line with space with powershell

Tags: powershell, replace, line, newline

Hi so I've been looking into this for a while and nothing I've tried has worked. Forgive me for asking this again, but I cannot replace a new line with a space in powershell

```
$path = "$root\$filename"
Get-Content $path | % $_.Replace "`r`n"," " | Set-Content "$root\bob.txt" -Force
```

This is one of the many things I've tried just looking around on this site.

I'm using powershell v3

Answer (score 6):

A couple of issues here.  First, the way you are calling Get-Content, the strings sent down the pipe will never have a newline in them. That's because the default way Get-Content works is to split the file up on newline and output a string for each line.  Second, your Foreach command requires {} around the replace command.  Try this:

```
Get-Content $path -Raw | Foreach {$_ -replace "`r`n",' '} | 
    Set-Content $root\bob.txt -Force
```

The `-Raw` parameter instructs `Get-Content` to read the file contents in as a single string.  This will preserve the `CRLFs`.

Answer (score 6):

[Keith Hill's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953971/45375) explains the problem with your code well and provides a working solution.

However, Keith's solution adds a *trailing space* to the output line (as your own solution attempt would have done, had it worked).

Here's a simpler alternative that avoids this problem.

```
(Get-Content $path) -join ' ' | Set-Content -Force $root\bob.txt
```

- `(Get-Content $path)` returns an *array* of lines,
- which we then *join* to form a single output string, with elements *separated* by a space each - this logic only places the separator (a space) *between* elements, and not also at the end.

Note that both this and Keith's answer require reading the entire input file into memory, which is potentially problematic with large files.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you haven't changed `$OFS` from its default value of `' '` (a single space):

```
[string](Get-Content $path) | Set-Content -Force $root\bob.txt
```

or

```
"$(Get-Content $path)" | Set-Content -Force $root\bob.txt
```

`$OFS` is an automatic variable that specifies at separator that will be used to separate the elements of an array with it is cast to `[string]`.  Its default value is a space, and `Get-Content` will return an array of the lines in the file, removing the CRLF. Casting that to `[string]` then produces a space-separated string of the lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$NewStr = "";
Get-Content $Path -Raw | ForEach {$NewStr += "$_ "}
$NewStr | Set-Content DestinationPath -Force
```